# Get value from custom Dialog in Android

Tags: android

I'm using custom Adapter to show contacts in listview and I create onClick function which open custom dialog when any item click. After that I want to get contact number from dialog box but when I try to get it an error popup.

```
IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
```

**Custom Dialog From Custom Adapter**

```
// Other code
// This code is working fine problem is in activity class
public void onClick(View v) {
              Toast.makeText(context, "Item click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              String phoneNumber = phone.getText().toString();
              String userName = name.getText().toString();
              final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
              dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
              dialog.setTitle(userName);
              EditText etxtContactNumber = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etxtContactNumber);
              etxtContactNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
              dialog.show();
            }
// reset of the code
```

**Custom Dialog**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etxtContactNumber" />

<Button
    android:text="Send SMS"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />

<Button
    android:text="Phone Call"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnPhoneCall"
    android:onClick="phoneCall" />
```

**Main Activity**

```
protected void sendMessage(View view){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Send Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    EditText etxtContactNumber = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etxtContactNumber);
    String phoneNumber = etxtContactNumber.getText().toString();
    String uri= "smsto:"+phoneNumber;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I know the reason of error `etxtContactNumber` is not in this view. This is also not in main activity view then where it is how can I get it.
**Custom adapter and MainActivity both are two different files**

Comment: use `public void sendMessage`

Comment: `public` is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create `dialog` in customAdapter and want to get the value in MainActivity just create dialog as `public static` and initialize it in contractor

**Custom Adapter**

```
 public static Dialog dialog;
  customAdapter(Context ctx){
        dialog = new Dialog(ctx);
  }
```

**Main Activity**

```
  dialog.findViewById(R.id.etxtContactNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please us the below line to infalte the custom view by

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_filter, parent, false);
```

and after then

```
 EditText etxtContactNumber = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.etxtContactNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to etxtContactNumber text from your custom adapter.

You must create a customDialog.java class and do below code at onCreate().

```
setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
setTitle(userName);
EditText etxtContactNumber =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtContactNumber);
etxtContactNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
```

You must do below code at onClick of custom adapter.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.show();
```

Hope this will fix your issue.